# Converting PHP into Codeigniter framework

Tags: php, codeigniter

Please help I cannot solve how to correctly convert my old PHP into Codeigniter, to get JSON result as below.

```
{"data":[{"Category":{"Category_ID":"3","Category_name":"Camera","Category_image":"upload\/images\/7089-2015-07-09.png"}},{"Category":{"Category_ID":"9","Category_name":"Cars","Category_image":"upload\/images\/7789-2015-07-09.png"}},{"Category":{"Category_ID":"4","Category_name":"Clothes","Category_image":"upload\/images\/9350-2015-07-09.png"}},{"Category":{"Category_ID":"1","Category_name":"Computer","Category_image":"upload\/images\/1843-2015-07-09.png"}},{"Category":{"Category_ID":"7","Category_name":"Music","Category_image":"upload\/images\/8666-2015-07-09.png"}},{"Category":{"Category_ID":"5","Category_name":"Other","Category_image":"upload\/images\/6260-2015-07-09.png"}},{"Category":{"Category_ID":"2","Category_name":"Smartphone","Category_image":"upload\/images\/3025-2015-07-09.png"}},{"Category":{"Category_ID":"8","Category_name":"Sports","Category_image":"upload\/images\/5354-2015-07-09.png"}}]}
```

This my PHP version

```
<?php
include_once('../includes/connect_database.php'); 
include_once('../includes/variables.php');


        $sql_query = "SELECT * 
                FROM tbl_category 
                ORDER BY Category_name ASC ";

        $result = $connect->query($sql_query) or die ("Error :".mysql_error());

        $categories = array();
        while($category = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $categories[] = array('Category'=>$category);
        }

        // create json output
        $output = json_encode(array('data' => $categories));

//Output the output.
echo $output;

include_once('../includes/close_database.php');?>
```

This is my codeigniter version

```
public function prop_get() {

    //$data = null;
    $category = $this->db->get('kategori')->result();

    //$category = $this->Wilayah_model->get_category2();
    $categories[] = array('Category' => $category);

    $this->response(array('data' => $categories));

}
```

Thank you

Comment: try changing `result()` into `result_array()`

Comment: Hi Sanjit, Thank you, but I tried that and the result showed {"data":[{"Category":[{"Category_ID":"1","Category_name":"Bali"},...  

What I need 

{"data":[{"Category":{"Category_ID":"3",

Comment: I think you need to add order_by when converting to Codeigniter to have the same result

Comment: Hi catcon, I tried using order by, when I got the exact result I need as {"data":[{"Category":{"Category_ID":"3", –, but in the middle got this error {"Category":{"conn_id":{"affected_rows":null,"client_info":null,"client_version":null,"connect_errno":null,"connect_error":null,"errno":null,"error":null,"error_list":null,"field_count":null,"host_info":null,"info":null,"insert_id":null,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would do it (using Query Builder as I am a fan ...)

```
<?php
include_once('../includes/connect_database.php'); 
include_once('../includes/variables.php');

        // Using query builder for ease
        $db->order_by('Category_name ASC');
        $data = $db->get('tbl_category')->result_array();

        foreach ($data as $row){
            $categories[] = array('Category'=>$row);
        }

        $output = json_encode(array('data' => $categories));
```

Does that fix your problem?

Comment: Thank you Antony for your help. I finally get the format I need. I modified into this     $data = $this->db->get('kategori')->result_array();

        foreach ($data as $row){
            $categories[] = array('Category'=>$row);
        }

        $output = json_encode(array('data' => $categories));

        echo $output;

Comment: Great :) Glad it helped